# CentOS7 ccollab with perforce CL update issue

Tags: centos7, perforce, code-collaborator

I cant get codecollaborator to upload files to for code review. I suspect I am missing some config. I have been scouring perforce and smartbear and stackover flow pages for a couple hours now no luck

CENTOS7
p4 (cant seem to find the version)
Collaborator Enterprise v11.2.11200

**My p4 works totally fine have been using for months now to create CLs and submit.** But now i need to upload files for code reviews.

command i ran to setup ccollab:

```
wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.smartbear/collaborator/11.2.11200/ccollab_client_11_2_11200_unix.sh

chmod +x ccollab_client_11_2_11200_unix.sh

./ccollab_client_11_2_11200_unix.sh
```

*(went through install accepting entering as prompted)*

```
ccollab login https://<codecollaborator_server> <username>
```

the above logs in fine no errors

```
ccollab --no-browser --scm perforce --server-proxy-host https://codecollaborator_server --p4user <username> --p4charset utf8 --p4client local_workspace_name --p4 /bin/p4 set
```

the try to upload a file

```
ccollab --debug addchangelist new 123456789
```

and get the following output:

Connecting to server at https://

Connected to Collaborator Enterprise v11.2.11200

Connected as:

```
Attaching changelists to review
Auto-detecting SCM System for '/my/workspace/path'
Checking client configuration for '/my/workspace/path'.
ERROR: Could not configure SCM system:
SCM system could not be auto-detected, but there was an error: Cannot run program "accurev" (in directory "/my/workspace/path"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

I tried to find what the "accurev" package is or how to use it but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Accurev is a different source control system.  Sounds like Code Collab doesn't know that it's supposed to be using Perforce?